# $_POST for disabled select

Tags: php, html, post

```
<select class="txtbx1" name="country" disabled>

<option value='FR' >FRANCE</option><option value='CH' selected>SWITZERLAND</option>
</select>
```

the above code is inside a form whose method is post

but `echo $_POST['country']` is showing nothing.. on the other hand if I remove disabled from select `$_POST['country']` is showing the correct result

Comment: try using `disabled="disabled"` instead

Comment: When you disable a field, its value is not submitted to the server.

Comment: then what shud i do in that case.. i need to disable the field

Comment: @anamus: "I need this lightbulb to be turned off, but it still has to produce light". You can't have it both ways. If you need the field submitted, then it can't be disabled.

Comment: @anamus: If you need it disabled then you are keeping the default value, it seems like you don't need the user input through the $_POST value. Maybe you can simply hardcode the value?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is how the `disabled` attribute works. When a form control is disabled, the value will be ignored when the form is submitted and the key will not be present in `$_POST` (or `$_GET`).

If you want the value to be present in the submitted data, but you don't want the user to be able to change the value on the page (which I imagine is what you are trying to acheive) use `readonly="readonly"` instead of `disabled="disabled"`.

**EDIT**

The `<select>` element does not have a `readonly` attribute. The above information still stands as it *will* work for `<input>`s and `<textarea>`s.

The solution to your problem here would be to disable the select and use a hidden input to send the value back to the server - e.g.

When the select is enabled:

```
<select class="txtbx1" name="country">
  <!-- options here -->
</select>
```

...and when it is disabled:

```
<select class="txtbx1" name="country_disabled" disabled="disabled">
  <!-- options here, with appropriate value having `selected="selected"` -->
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="value_of_field" />
```

Comment: @Rocket Indeed it doesn't, I just tested this after posting and it doesn't work. My answer still stands as valid because it will work for `<input>`s but I will update it regarding `<select>`s

Comment: I was reading the answer, and was like "wait, that's not right" :-)

Answer (score 5):

This is the correct behavior.  `disabled` disables the element, and does not send it's value when a form is POSTed.

You can use JavaScript to un-disable the form before you submit it.  Something like this (untested):

```
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++){
        var child = this.children[i];
        if(child.disabled){
            child.disabled = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: +1, although bad practice to rely on JS for core site functionality - JS should be used to enhance a site, not to make it work ;-)

Comment: @Dave: Agreed, just an alternate solution to yours.

Answer (score 0):

How your form tag looks like? You may have forgotten the `method="post"` attribute...

Comment: no I havent.. the thing works whn I dont hve the "disabled" attribute

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is have a "readonly select" - that is show the user what the choices are without allowing it to change and have it sent with the POST variables, you want to use "selected" on the option with the current value, and "disabled" on all the other options.  This will essentially show the select with all its options but only allow the current one to be selected.

I find this more helpful than simply having a disabled select.

As others have noted, you still need to insure that the server side doesn't accept changes to the field (as with any readonly field).