# Post a disabled select field PHP

Tags: php, html, post, html-select

I found this answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/7244888/1473523, but in my situation am I not able to put a hidden field, so is there no way to do post a disabled select field in PHP?

Comment: You can enable it using javascript before submit

Comment: use readonly instead of disabled, like the answers say?

Comment: I dont want to enabled it, because it have to be blank but I want the server should recognize it when I submit it and post even its null, but sometimes can it be enabled and then I dont want to submit the form if the value is null

Comment: Do you have any ECMA(JS) scripting available? Is POST request processed by PHP? If so, can you just test for `isset($_POST[$fieldName]])`

Comment: Possibly because the answer you linked to already answers your question. No, there is no way to do this. That's the whole point of disabling the field.

Comment: This is crazy, because I thought there is a way to do this as I asked in my question, this is really not fair to downvote because of this.

Comment: It was speculation on my part. I did not downvote you. But it's not crazy. It's a downvote, and you shouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that's what disabling the field does: Prevents the value from being posted back to the server. If you're disabling the field, you should *know* its value as it can't be changed. You shouldn't *need* the value to be posted back.

If the value is changing based on some other input, you should capture that input server-side and use it to calculate the value that *would* have been posted back, the same way you calculated which value to select client-side. Relying on the client-side calculated value to be accurate is a serious security flaw.

Your options are to somehow enable the field before the form is posted, or add a hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove attribute disabled with javascript just before submiting your form.

Answer (score 0):

From the question that you posted, this is how a disable field is created:

`<select class="txtbx1" name="country_disabled" disabled="disabled">`

You can make it hidden as well:

```
<select class="txtbx1" name="country_disabled" type="hidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on the client for stuff like this. They can have JS disabled or craft a request using developer tools from the browser or a tool like Fiddler.

If there is a value you expect but that the user is not allowed to change, keep it serverside. Use sessions, for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no way** to post a disabled field, if it was it would be a non-sense.

So either you define a default value on the server side when no value are submitted or either you use `<input type="hidden" name="same_as_select" value="default" />` to provide a default value, then, if your form is enabled, it will always override the default value.

Answer (score 0):

No, there no way even, but you can test if that field is empty to prevent undefined index notice:

```
if(empty($_POST['select_name'])){ //or !isset()
  $disabled_select = 0; //or its default value
} else {
  $disabled_select = $_POST['select_name'];
}
```

I prefer to use single line:

```
$disabled_select = empty($_POST['select_name']) ? 0 : $_POST['select_name'];
```